# Is there a simple way to change the plot axis decimal indicator from point to comma in base R?

Tags: r

I am making this simple plot

```
plot(data.frame(a=c(0.5,1,1.5,2,2.5,3,3.5,4),
                 b=c(0.01,0.02,0.03,0.04,0.05,0.06,0.07,0.08)))
```

I´ve seem lots off questions about how to make the axis decimal indicator a comma on ggplot2, but didn't find any on base R.
I'm thinking something that adjust to the axis scale if the range of the data changes.
I know one could use `xaxt = "n"` and paste the values as text but wonder how that works with diferent ranges
Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `options(OutDec = ",")`.

```
plot(data.frame(a=c(0.5,1,1.5,2,2.5,3,3.5,4),
                b=c(0.01,0.02,0.03,0.04,0.05,0.06,0.07,0.08)))
```

[image]